# delphi 5 apps display something wrong on the panel in win7 x64

Tags: delphi

I moved the delphi 5 app to win 7 x64. But I saw the panel didn't show as well as it was in Win XP. I tried to fix the height and resize in the OnResize, but failed. Let's say there are 2 panels in a form, panel1 and panel2. panel1.align=alleft and panel2.align=alclient. panel2 is in panel1. but in Win 7 x64, the panel2 didn't full fill its parent. is this because the delphi is too old that i need to change a new version?

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: And some code. You don't have enough rep for a screenshot, but just put one on a file sharing site and I'll upload it here.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something like this, althought usually some more complicated layout is involved than just two panels. Adding few `panel.Realign;` calls in appropriate places (ie in form's `OnShow` event) have fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think such issues occurred when a form is displayed on screen, with its state as maximized. Is it your case?

What I've done to fix it is that I created the form not as maximized, but on screen center, then add a custom message just after the form is shown:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
 (...)
    procedure WMUser(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER;
 (...)


procedure TMyForm .FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (...)
  PostMessage(Handle,WM_USER,0,0); // avoid Vista and Seven screen refresh bug
end;

procedure TMyForm .WMUser(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

Comment: `WindowState := wsMaximized;` in onShow works for me (Win7). Could you elaborate when could it be a problem, please ?

Comment: I've seen it to be a problem with Windows Seven (at least with Delphi 7, and with some third-party components like the TMS Ribbon). Putting a dedicated custom message to set it *after* `OnShow` did the trick, since it was processed *after* the form is actually fully created and painted for the first time. I found out that some events were called before maximization, as far as I remember.

Comment: it's funny I've stumbled this problem for the 1st time in my life just 2 days after asking you :). One user had custom simplified look in Win7 and somehow anchors for DBGrid, buttons, etc worked wrong - maximized window, but all elements stayed on their former places, so there were a lot of blank space to the right and down. But after form is shown, anchors begin to work and resizing moves and shrinks it, with all that empty space. Ugly. I've solved that with pretty random clicks on random properties :), probably I should use your advise, but frankly I afraid to touch it. Delphi 6 btw

Comment: Just in case. I've found out what my problem was. `Form.BorderStyle` should be `bsSingle`, not `bsSizeable` before maximizing.